# RSA encryption - trying to encrypt a message returns wrong values

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, biginteger

I am putting values for each of the variables to get the encrypted message. All are hard-coded in for testing purposes.

This returns the value `?????` when it should return `538 1729 1328 1328 2146`. Is there something I put in wrong? This is the only problem I am having with my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int p = 61;
    int q = 37;
    int pq = p * q;
    int phiPQ = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
    int e = 7;
    int d = 1543;
    String message = encryptMsg("hello", pq, e);
    System.out.println(message);
}

public static String encryptMsg(String msg, int pq, int e){
    BigInteger bE = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(e));
    BigInteger bPQ = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(pq));
    String encryptedMsg = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++){
        BigInteger m = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(msg.charAt(i)));
        BigInteger bC = m.modPow(bE, bPQ);
        encryptedMsg += " " + (char)bC.intValue();
    }
    return encryptedMsg;
}
```

Comment: Btw: The first value of the result is 1039, not 538.

Answer (score 1):

i think you probably want

```
encryptedMsg +=" " + bC.toString();
```

currently you're casting the integer to a character, so getting back unicode, i guess, while what you seem to be expecting is integers as strings.